# How to save image to database cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have been having some trouble uploading images using cakephp and saving the image's path to the database. While the code I have uploads the image fine, it does not add the url to the database... I am not totally sure how to do that.

Here is my controller code:

```
<?php

 class PhotosController extends AppController {

   public function photo() {
        $filename = '';
        if ($this->request->is('post')) { // checks for the post values

         $uploadData = $this->data['uploadFile']['pdf_path'];

            if ( $uploadData['size'] == 0 || $uploadData['error'] !== 0) { //             checks for the errors and size of the uploaded file
                return false;
            }
            $filename = basename($uploadData['name']); // gets the base name of the uploaded file
            $uploadFolder = WWW_ROOT. 'files';  // path where the uploaded file has to be saved
            $filename = time() .'_'. $filename; // adding time stamp for the uploaded image for uniqueness
            $uploadPath =  $uploadFolder . DS . $filename;
            if( !file_exists($uploadFolder) ){
                mkdir($uploadFolder); // creates folder if  not found
            }
            if (!move_uploaded_file($uploadData['tmp_name'], $uploadPath)) {
                return false;
            }

                 if (!empty($this->request->data)) {

             $this->Photo->create();
             $this->Photo->save($this->request->data['Photo']['url']);
             $this->Session->setFlash(__('Product Has Been Added'));

}


        }
       $this->set('image',$filename);

}
```

}

This allows me to save to fileserver however I am not too sure how to save the url to the filepath to the database.

When I add

```
  $this->Photo->create();
  $this->Photo->save($this->request->data);
  $this->Session->setFlash(__('Photo Has Been Added'));
```

A database entry is saved however this does not contain the file path in the "url" column of the 'photos' table.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: not sure what your exact problem is: you don't know how to create the url path to save it in the database? or you have the path but it doesn't get updated? Are you inserting or updating a record?

Comment: Saving binary data to a DB is performance wise a pretty stupid thing to do for a web application.

Comment: I am not saving binary data to the Database, what I am trying to do is save the filepath to the database. The url path has been created and is within the $filename variable, however I do not know how to get this path to save to the database.

The save() function at the bottom only creates a new row in the database, the filepath is not saved.

Comment: Then, if your `$this->request->data` array has everything else, and assuming you have a column `url` in the database for your photo, just do `$this->request->data['Photo']['url'] = $filename; $this->Photo->create();$this->Photo->save($this->request->data);`

Comment: Use `@` if you mention others like @Nunser

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved your question, consider closing it if you think it's not going to help anyone else in the future. If you consider it deserves to have an answer so someone else may read, answer it yourself with the solution, or tell me and I'll give an "official" answer. Ooooor, if it "help", but didn't solve the actual problem, update your question with more details of the error to help you further :)

Comment: It did help and solve the issue, so you can make it the official answer